# Return user info in Sentry2

Tags: laravel, cartalyst-sentry

I want to return the users info to my view when a user logs in but I keep getting an error message that says "Undefined variable: user"

Here is my controller code:

```
public function postLogin()
{
    $credentials = array(
        'email'    => \Input::get('email'),
        'password' => \Input::get('password')
    );

    try
    {
        $user = \Sentry::authenticate($credentials, false);

        if ($user);
        {
            $user = \Sentry::getUser();
            \Notification::succes('Succesvol ingelogd als,'. $user->name);
            return \Redirect::back()-with($user);
        }
    }
        catch(\Exception $e)
    {
        \Notification::error($e->getMessage());
        return \Redirect::back();
    }
}
```

and in my view I try to use the $user variable but then I get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do:

```
Redirect::back()->with('user',$user);
```

In your new request you must get the user from the Session:

```
$user = Session::get('user');
```

and pass it to your view:

```
return View::make('view')->with('user', $user);
```

Because Laravel **doesn't create global variables** as it does when you:

```
return View::make('view')->with('variableName', $value);
```